# How to fix this issue with React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to create a new react-native mobile application. However, there's a problem when I added the react native navigation (stack, bottom).

Whenever the app loads for the first time or if it opens the screen for the first time, the header part of the stack navigation expands first and then went back to its normal size. Same with the bottom navigation, it expands and went back to its normal size. Not really sure to explain it in English but I took a video and convert it to gif to give you the clear view about the issue.

[image: issue]

Installed the latest version of the packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1"
  }
```

**Index.js**

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './app/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

I even tried to use the older version of the package but still the same issue. Tried both android physical device and emulator.

This is the same issue with https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8446 and https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8620

Answer (score 0):

i suggest dont using deafaul header of screen and implementing it yourself, native-base for react give you a nice way to do it, and for removing default header, search for it in react navigation, as i remeber you shold pass a prop for it to be removed

Comment: It's not only about the default header. Even when I tried to use bottom tab navigation, it has the same issue. It expands and then it return to the original size. I tried to create an new project using expo and there's no problem encountered. It renders correctly, but when I ejected it, the problem shows just like what happen on a bare react native project.

Comment: so why you eject?

Comment: I need to use appodeal sdk and won't work with expo so I need to eject it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a customized header component and add that directly to your screen component. `react-navigation` headers are tricky to handle.

Also, use `react-native-cli` that gives flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is to use `SafeAreaProvider` see the [doc](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context)